# Convert pivot table generated from pivottabler package to dataframe

Tags: r, pivot, pivot-table

I'm trying to make a pivot table with `pivottabler` package. I want to convert the pivot table object to dataframe, so that I can convert it to data table (with DT) and render it in Shiny app, so that it's downloadable.

```
library(pivottabler)
pt = qpvt(mtcars, 'cyl', 'vs', 'n()')
```

I tried to convert it to matrix

```
as.data.frame(pt)
```

I got error message like below:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(pt) : cannot coerce class ‘c("PivotTable", "R6")’ to a data.frame
```

Does anyone know how to convert the pivot table object to dataframe?

Comment: pivottabler has a built in function for dataframes --> `pt$asDataFrame()`. There is also a lot of framework for rendering in Shiny --> `pivottabler(pt)` see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pivottabler/versions/1.2.0/vignettes/v04-outputs.Rmd

Comment: Thank you.   For rendering in Shiny,  is that easily downloadable like data table?  That's the problem I have with rpivotTable package. @M. Viking

Comment: Hi @zesla, let me see if I understand; you want to render in shiny and allow the user download the pivottabler data, correct?   For more on pivottabler and shiny see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pivottabler/versions/1.2.0/vignettes/v11-shiny.Rmd ... and for adding a data download button to shiny see https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html and https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadHandler.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an `R6` class.  One option would be to extract with `asDataFrame` which can be revealed if we check the `str`

```
str(pt)
#...
#...
#asDataFrame: function (separator = " ", stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors()) 
#asJSON: function () 
#asList: function () 
#asMatrix: function (includeHeaders = TRUE, repeatHeaders = FALSE, rawValue = FALSE) 
#asTidyDataFrame: function (includeGroupCaptions = TRUE, includeGroupValues = TRUE, 
...
```

Therefore, applying `asDataFrame()` on the R6 object

```
out <- pt$asDataFrame()
out
#     0  1 Total
#4      1 10    11
#6      3  4     7
#8     14 NA    14
#Total 18 14    32

str(out)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ 0    : int  1 3 14 18
#$ 1    : int  10 4 NA 14
#$ Total: int  11 7 14 32
```

or to get a `matrix`, `asMatrix`

```
pt$asMatrix()
#      [,1]    [,2] [,3] [,4]   
#[1,] ""      "0"  "1"  "Total"
#[2,] "4"     "1"  "10" "11"   
#[3,] "6"     "3"  "4"  "7"    
#[4,] "8"     "14" ""   "14"   
#[5,] "Total" "18" "14" "32"
```