# How to convert rpivotTable result in to dataframe

Tags: r, rpivottable

How to convert rpivotTable result in to dataframe. 
I want to create new datafrmae with the result of rpivotTable,

Is it possible do in R?

Data Set Like

```
User     Order_Bin
a          PPL
b          CCD
c          CCD
d          OLP
a          OLP
c          PPL
b          OLP
a          PPL
a          OLP
b          PPL
c          CCD
d          CCD
d          OLP
c          OLP
b          OLP
b          CCD
```

How to get result of below code as data.frame

```
library(rpivotTable)
rpivotTable(
  inventory,
  aggregatorName = "Count",
  cols = "Order_Bin",
  rows = "User",
  rendererName = "Heatmap",
  width = "100%",
  height = "1000px")
```

Comment: Did you search this site? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410154/convert-pivot-table-generated-from-pivottabler-package-to-dataframe

Comment: @Edward: The question https://stackoverflow.com/q/56410154/3817004 you have linked to uses _another package_ `pivottabler` which is different to `rpivotTable` which is used in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documention of `rpivotTable`, there is no export facility.

So, you have to aggregate on your own. One possibility is

```
reshape2::dcast(inventory, User ~ Order_Bin, length, margins = TRUE)
```

which returns

> ```
>    User CCD OLP PPL (all)
> 1     a   0   2   2     4
> 2     b   2   2   1     5
> 3     c   2   1   1     4
> 4     d   1   2   0     3
> 5 (all)   5   7   4    16
> ```

For comparison, here is the output of the `pivotTable()` call:

[image]

Please, note the *Totals* row and column.

Comment: Use of pivotTable not working for me in community lots of people facing same issue, its Stop flexdashboard, And thanks for the help, dcast working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The data frame is stored in the list, along with the row and col variable names, and the aggregatorName.

```
library(rpivotTable)
pv <- rpivotTable(
  df,
  aggregatorName = "Count",
  cols = "Order_Bin",
  rows = "User",
  rendererName = "Heatmap",
  width = "100%",
  height = "1000px")
```

---

```
class(pv)
str(pv)
List of 8
 $ x            :List of 4
  ..$ data     :'data.frame':   16 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ User     : chr [1:16] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
  .. ..$ Order_Bin: chr [1:16] "PPL" "CCD" "CCD" "OLP" ...
  ..$ params   :List of 4
  .. ..$ rows          :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ : chr "User"
  .. ..$ cols          :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ : chr "Order_Bin"
  .. ..$ aggregatorName:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ : chr "Count"  # etc. ...
```

---

This information can then be used to create the **data frame** you asked for containing the **results** of the pivotTable:

```
pv$x$data %>%
  group_by(Order_Bin, User) %>%
  count() %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols=User, names_from=Order_Bin, values_from=n, 
              values_fill=list(n=0))
```

---

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  User    CCD   OLP   PPL
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 b         2     2     1
2 c         2     1     1
3 d         1     2     0
4 a         0     2     2
```

---

Edit:
To get row percentages:

```
pv$x$data %>%
  group_by(Order_Bin, User) %>%
  count() %>% 
  group_by(User) %>%
  mutate(n=n/sum(n)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols=User, names_from=Order_Bin, values_from=n, 
              values_fill=list(n=0))
```

---

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   User [4]
  User    CCD   OLP   PPL
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 b     0.4   0.4    0.2 
2 c     0.5   0.25   0.25
3 d     0.333 0.667  0   
4 a     0     0.5    0.5
```

Comment: Well, yes that's the input data but without the margins (totals).

Comment: This is the same as expected but i also want to do, For this code
 `pv1 <-rpivotTable(sub_data,  
            aggregatorName = "Count as Fraction of Rows",  
            rows = "User",  
            cols = c("Order_Bin"), 
            rendererName = "Heatmap")`
it not working.I want to apply rbind for join both the tables. is it possible?

Comment: Sorry - I can't understand what you are asking. ;(

Comment: I want to displayed result with percentage under the CCD, OLP, PPL
Like for User C 2 1 1 so percentage will be 50% 25% 25% total 100% which divided in Bin. By using `pv1 <-rpivotTable(sub_data, aggregatorName = "Count as Fraction of Rows", rows = "User", cols = c("Order_Bin"), rendererName = "Heatmap")` i get values of percentage but i want this values in datafram